# xcode taks forver to upload file.ips

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I want to upload an app to the app store but the organizer takes forever to upload and most of the time it takes no further action, just stuck on "Uploading package to the app store"
I have uploaded several apps before and never encounter this issue...but this is the second app to face this issue with and it really drives me crazy

[image: Screen shot of the organizer]

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching someone suggested to disable firewall but it was disabled already on my case so I enabled it, and guess what,It worked...what is more confusing is that I had to reupload the version and the same issue appeared again so I disabled the firewall and  it worked agin...so, in conclusion, try to change your firewall setting and see whether it will work correctly or not